# How to remove a hidden column in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, ddl

When a new column is added with `DEFAULT xxx NULL` in Oracle 12, some data dictionary magic happens, and a hidden column is created:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (i NUMBER);

ALTER TABLE bar ADD (d NUMBER DEFAULT 1 NULL);

SELECT column_name, data_type, hidden_column 
  FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'BAR';

COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE  HIDDEN_COLUMN
I             NUMBER     NO
SYS_NC00002$  RAW        YES
D             NUMBER     NO
```

According to [DDL Optimization in Oracle Database 12c](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/ddl-optimizaton-in-odb12c-2331068.html), the hidden column is helping with this new feature.

**How can this hidden column be removed?**

I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE newbar AS SELECT * FROM bar;
```

which works, but all dependent objects (comments, triggers, grants indices etc) have to be recreated, which is bad.

Dropping unused columns doesn't help:

```
ALTER TABLE bar DROP UNUSED COLUMNS;
SELECT column_name, data_type, hidden_column 
  FROM user_tab_cols WHERE table_name = 'BAR';

COLUMN_NAME   DATA_TYPE  HIDDEN_COLUMN
I             NUMBER     NO
SYS_NC00002$  RAW        YES
D             NUMBER     NO
```

Moving the table doesn't help either:

```
ALTER TABLE bar MOVE;
```

According to Doc Id 2277937.1, the feature can be disabled in advance with

```
ALTER SESSION SET "_add_col_optim_enabled" = FALSE;
```

But I am really looking for a statement like

```
ALTER TABLE bar MOVE ...
```

to stops the magic and remove the hidden column.

Comment: I would have thought that `DROP UNUSED COLUMNS` should be enough. But rather than including your solution in the question you should post an answer and accept that. Otherwise your question will remain open

Comment: Done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50600052/how-to-drop-columns-in-a-compressed-table

Comment: You created a new _question_ not an _answer_.

Comment: It's really two problems: a) hidden column caused by drop column: new question, I'm writing the answer right now. b) hidden column caused by add columnd default 1 null:  this question, I'm still looking for an answer

Answer (score 1):

Nothing but `alter table BAR drop column D;`

( I issued on `DB ver. 12.1.0.2` )

Comment: Hmm. Then the hidden column would be gone (presumably unless the table was compressed). But as soon as I add the column again, the hidden column would reappear.

Comment: @wolφi yes, the hidden column reappears, as soon as the column added.